# Got error on installing CiviCRM on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I tried to install civiCRM with Drupal 8 following this https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/better-way-install-civicrm-drupal-8 but I am unable to do so. I am getting the following error:

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core/packages/DB.php' (include_path='.;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\packages;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/vendor/tecnickcom;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/archive_tar;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/auth_sasl;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/console_getopt;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/log;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/mail;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/net_smtp;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/net_socket;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/pear_exception;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard;D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib;.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Myprograms\php\civicrm\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\install\civicrm.php on line 151

I am getting the above error when installing CiviCRM module. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it works on Windows, but had the same problem yesterday with Ubuntu. Fixed by forcing the directory structure to be writable by both the Apache user and the user I'm logged in as—by default, some of those directories were unwritable and the install failed halfway through.

Note: failing halfway through was an unrecoverable state, I had to revert to a recent backup and start over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's possible but there was some discussion in chat that the poster's problem might have to do with the archive_tar library on windows having some problems.